# Option from dropdown list not being selected in Selenium & JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list with values and i am getting this error message when trying to select the values (cannot share the link because it is hidden):

```
Element: [[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (4aeb1bf64ec7a13956b6b0b2cf24d9ca)] -> xpath: //*[@id="Datatable_ReceiptListModel"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[10]/select]] -> xpath: .//option[normalize-space(.) = "Option 1"]]
```

The HTML for that dropdown is:

```
<select class="select-submotive inputs-table hide-in-partial" style="visibility: visible;">
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
            <option value="5">Option 1</option>
            <option value="6">Option 2</option>
    </select>
```

The XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="Datatable_ReceiptListModel"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]/select
```

I did this:

```
        Select dropdown736  = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Datatable_ReceiptListModel\"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[10]/select")));
        dropdown736.selectByVisibleText("Option 1");
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: The error message is not complete I guess. Please share the full output you are getting. Try to click the dropdown element before define `Select` object.

Comment: Use this for the select locator: //select[@class='select-submotive inputs-table hide-in-partial']

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.CSS, "option[value='5']")
option.click()
```

You can also click on element by text using Xpath, like this:

```
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.Xpath, "//option[text()='Option 1']")
option.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly fine for me:

```
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("file:///Users/sanders/Desktop/selenium/index.html");
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='select-submotive inputs-table hide-in-partial']")));
        select.selectByVisibleText("Option 1");
```

For this html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="select-submotive inputs-table hide-in-partial" style="visibility: visible;">
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
            <option value="5">Option 1</option>
            <option value="6">Option 2</option>
    </select>

</body>
```

[image]